# Upgrade Windows Server 2008R2 to support SNI

Tags: windows, iis, sni

I have a "Windows Server 2008 R2" with the "IIS7.5" and stumble now, when it comes to the topic of SSL: IIS7 does not support SNI.

How can SNI be retrofitted or alternatively how can I install "IIS8" (which does support SNI) on WIN2008R2?

Here what I want in bullet points:

- IIS7.5 SNI retrofit?

or how can I

- IIS8 Install on WIN2008R2?

Comment: so the phrase "upgrade windows server 2008r2 didn't ring any bells?

Comment: Disagree that this question is a duplicate. It may already have an _answer_ elsewhere: but this _question_ is not the question being asked in the alleged duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

SNI is not supported in IIS 7.5, and you can't upgrade IIS, because each version of Windows Server comes with its own version of IIS, which can't be changed.

You need at least IIS 8, so you need to use at least Windows Server 2012.